# Thumbnail: i need to have a fixed width and variable height (in proportion)

Tags: 7, media

I need to fix the width of the thumbnail at 200px, while the height has to be resized proportionally; i've seen that i can fix the width x height for thumbnails, but need to set only one dimension....how can i do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the image styles settings for the "Scale" action:

> Scaling will maintain the aspect-ratio of the original image. If only
>   a single dimension is specified, the other dimension will be
>   calculated.

So if you specify just the width to 200px, the height will be calculated while maintaining the aspect ratio of the original image.